# Cannot access the [bbbb::100] server page in 6lbr

Tags: raspberry-pi

I installed 6lbr on raspbian wheezy and when I run the server, I got a messages as "6LoWPAN border router started" but I am unable to access the [bbbb::100] server page. Also when I check "ifconfig", im able to see only eth0 and lo0 interfaces only. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: Welcome aboard! You will probably get a better answer if you delete this question and ask it again on our sister site https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ But, DO NOT leave it open on two sites as it would be closed as duplicate and then you wouldn't get an answer. Good luck  :-)

Comment: No problem. Welcome aboard. we are here to help :-) And hopefully you can help others too.